# Can't move bg to the middle somehow

Tags: css

[image: http://prntscr.com/97sgvp]

So basically I want to move the white background to the middle/center
with a width 65% and height 100%

```
.middlebg {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;``
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
```

Comment: What is the html behind the white and black backgrounds?

Comment: Try `margin: 0 auto;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is setting the margin in the middlebg class to `margin: 0 auto` the first value being the vertical margin and the second being the horizontal margin. Setting the horizontal margin to auto will centre this element for you.

http://codepen.io/lostdino/pen/rOEEPr

```
body {
  background: black;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.middlebg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 65%;
  height: 80px;
  background:white;
}
```